# Autowired repository gets a nullPointerException error everytime i try to insert data in mysql database (on springboot java)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

So i've been trying to add some new data in another class which i create myself (not in the default class below the Controller)

so here's the code to explain it:

MainController.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import hello.User;
import hello.UserRepository;

@Controller    
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") 
public class MainController {
    @Autowired 
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @GetMapping(path="/add")
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser () { 
        pge j = new pge();
        j.pgl();    //here's the code to add data in mysql
        return "Saved";
    }
}
```

and here's the code in my pge.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class pge {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    public void pgl() { 
        User n = new User();
        n.setName("sarah");
        n.setEmail("sarah@gmail.com");
        userRepository.save(n); 
    }
}
```

everytime i open localhost:8080/demo/add , in web it just gives whitelabel error page and in java it gives null error. all i want to do is just adding new data in my database (MySQL) in my own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `pge` object not managed by Spring, `autowired` annotation will not inject `UserRepository` bean. I will suggest changing `pge` to spring managed bean.

```
@Service
public class pge {

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;

   ...
}
```

And in Main Controller

```
@Controller    
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") 
public class MainController {

   @Autowired 
   private UserRepository userRepository;

   @Autowired 
   private pge pge;

   @GetMapping(path="/add")
   public @ResponseBody String addNewUser () { 
    pge.pgl();    //here's the code to add data in mysql
    return "Saved";
   }
}
```